# image not display in media library and thumbnail not display in post

Tags: uploads, media-library

some problems with importing images.

(1) Upload folder images do not appear in the wordpress media area. The upload folder is already with 755 permission.

(2) Thumbnail do not appear on the site. However, I can access the image by url. The images inside the post usually appear on the site. The problem is only in the thumbnail.

(3) In the post admin, the thumbnail area keeps loading and never leaves it. And change the highlighted image the upload folder photos do not appear.

Images have been manually uploaded to the upload folder as the default wordpress import / export does not work 100%.

Is there anything that can be done in the database to fix? What to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom theme, please add this in the `functions.php`:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```